# PHP Pick random array values based on total

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have array in php like

```
$randomarray = array('1106'=>'5','1110'=>'2','11867'=>'3','1206'=>'2','1210'=>'1','1223'=>'6','1235'=>'3','12565'=>'4','1258'=>'5','12690'=>'2','12693'=>'3','1283'=>'1','12944'=>'5');
```

I want to randomly pick elements from the array with the count of exactly 20. Each element have to only one time

I tried some array random example. I can't able to get the exact total which i expect.

this is the example of what i did that. But loop went to infinitive,

```
function randomTo($numIn) {
    global $randomarray;
    $numOut = 0;
    $numbers = array();

    do {
        $key = array_rand($randomarray );
        $add =  $mainarray[$key];
        if($numOut + $add > $numIn)
            continue;
        $numOut += $add;
        $numbers[] = $add;
        unset($mainarray[$key]);
    } while( $numOut != $numIn );

    return $numbers;
}
$testdata = randomTo(20);
```

Comment: [`shuffle`](http://php.net/shuffle)  and [`array_slice`](http://php.net/array_slice). Please show what you tried, and explain what specific issues you ran into. (Your input array has less than 20 elements, so how'd you want to get 20 unique ones?)

Comment: I am not picking 20 elements. I am picking the array values of 20.

Comment: Show an example of your picking criteria. "array values of 20" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @mario pls check the question. i updated the code snippet

Comment: I'd use slightly different approach here: 1) collect all combinations of keys that amount to 20 in a separate array; 2) choose randomly an element from that array.

Comment: @raina77ow how to collect all combination to exactly 20??

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you're trying to solve is called [Subset sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and it's a subset of the [Knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

Just google for it, and while you're at it, google for [Dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) as it's a way of approaching the problem.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(count($randomarray)) > 20
   print_r(array_rand($randomarray, 20));
```

Answer (score -1):

Get some Idea from this :

**An example for getting random value from arrays**

```
    $r = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $r[] = $arr[$i];
    }
    return $num == 1 ? $r[0] : $r;
}

$a = array("apple", "banana", "cherry");
print_r(array_random($a));
print_r(array_random($a, 2));
?>

cherry
Array
(
    [0] => banana
    [1] => apple
)
```

**And example for getting random value from assoc arrays;**

```
<?php
function array_random_assoc($arr, $num = 1) {
    $keys = array_keys($arr);
    shuffle($keys);

    $r = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num; $i++) {
        $r[$keys[$i]] = $arr[$keys[$i]];
    }
    return $r;
}

$a = array("a" => "apple", "b" => "banana", "c" => "cherry");
print_r(array_random_assoc($a));
print_r(array_random_assoc($a, 2));
?>

Array
(
    [c] => cherry
)
Array
(
    [a] => apple
    [b] => banana
)
```